# How to create a database with Visual Studio, also using UI?

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010

I made the UI side of the project, but now I need to have a database. How can I create it with Visual Studio 2010? I don't have any idea about how to retrieve data with C#. I know SQL but can you give me some examples of that (C# with SQL)?

Comment: do you get some money when your answer is accepted?

Comment: No, you get reputation points.

Comment: David Hoerster gave you a hint to get questions answered. If you aren't able to accept tips you are in the wrong place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Joe talks about and what the post by Scott Hanselman describes is called "Code First". With Entity Framework, there are two other (easy) ways to create a database with Visual Studio 2010 tooling.

One would be to use a Entity Data Model (.edmx) file to create your model (classic Entity Relationship model) and then right click on the model and choose "Generate Database from Model", connect to SQL server and you're done. This is called Model First.

The other technique, which is called "Database First", is when you have an existing Database (or you can create your database directly from SQL Server), and you create an Entity Data Model based on that (you actually get to choose between Database first and model first from the Add-> Entity Data Model dialog). You select the tables, views and stored procedures you want to add, hit finish and you're set.

in both cases, When you build your soultion, you get a data context class that you can use to access your data which is pretty straightforward as well (pretty much the same way as described in scott's blog post).

Comment: now I know what I want. I added a local database. Created the table etc. Now I am trying to find the way to access it with code. I know how to do it with php but not C#. Can you give me an example of that? For example, connecting, inserting, retrieving etc.

Comment: I don't need a very nice Database, I will just put some image id's and their paths, also their features like rgb, texture etc. But I am sooo far away from that now :)

Comment: for that you should use the second approache (Database first). here are some links that should help, they start from creating the database, creating the Entity Data Model, querying the database, etc. [From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399182.aspx) , [from DeVCURRY](http://www.devcurry.com/2010/12/learn-adonet-entity-framework-4-free.html) Hope this helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to do this, something you might want to take a look at is EF code first where you can create models in code and then generate the database based off of those models.

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SimpleCodeFirstWithEntityFramework4MagicUnicornFeatureCTP4.aspx